# How can i create a dynamic string format in C#

Tags: c#

I have as input the string format `CST-000000` and an integer with value `1`

Upon using

```
string result = string.Format("CST-000000", 1);
```

the expected result should be `CST-000001` instead of `CST-000000`

How could i create this string format dynamically?
For example

```
 - CST-000 should produce CST-001
 - HELLO000 should produce HELLO001
 - CUSTOMER0000 should produce CUSTOMER0001
```

Comment: replace last zero with `{0}`?

Comment: Is it true that the format string always ends in a number of zeros? Are you *just* replacing the last value with 1, or might you have larger values?

Comment: @canton7 yes that is true

Comment: Are those format strings fixed at compile time? Ie, do you know at compile time how many places you need?

Comment: It would help if you could give an example of the desired result with a value with more than one digit - on my now-deleted answer there were different interpretations of what you'd wan.t

Comment: Downvoting because the question is not being clarified. Until then it's not useful.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that:

- You receive your format string from somewhere and you can't control what it looks like
- Your format string ends with 1 or more zeros
- If the format string is e.g. CST-00000 and your value is 123, you want the result to be CST-00123

You can do something like this:

Inspect your format string, and separate out the stuff at the beginning from the zeros at the end. It's easy to do this with Regex, e.g.:

```
string format = "CST-000000";
// "Zero or more of anything, followed by one or more zeros at the end of the string"
var match = Regex.Match(format, "(.*?)(0+)$");
if (!match.Success)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Format must end with one or more zeros");  
}
string prefix = match.Groups[1].Value; // E.g. CST-
string zeros = match.Groups[2].Value; // E.g. 000000
```

Once you have these, note the "Zero placeholder" in [this list of custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) -- you can write e.g. `123.ToString("0000")` and the output will be `0123`. This lets you finish off with:

```
int value = 123;
string result = prefix + value.ToString(zeros);
```

[See it on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Um7H5)

Comment: Isn't regex an awful way in terms of performance to implement such feature ? Imagine if it's called thousands of times...

Comment: @AFract I wouldn't say it's awful. A benchmark shows the `Regex.Match` takes about 400ns on my machine. If it's on a hot path, you can use a cached `Regex` instance and get it down to less than 200ns.

Comment: @AFract First make it work. And if you notice it's a bottleneck, you can always try something different. Or as Donald Knuth puts it *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"* (Doesn't mean, you shouldn't think about performance at all before you start, though)

Comment: ... and if that doesn't work, and equivalent with a loop gets it down to 30ns or so. But it's 8 lines instead of 1 and the meaning isn't as clear

Answer (score 3):

[String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0) requires a placeholder `{n}` with a zero-based argument number. You can also add it a format `{n:format}`.

```cs
string result = String.Format("CST-{0:000000}", 1);
```

You can also use [String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation)

```
string result = $"CST-{1:000000}"
```

The difference is that instead of a placeholder you specify the value directly (or as an expression). Instead of the [Custom numeric format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings), you can also use the [Standard numeric format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) `d6`: `$"CST-{1:d6}"`

---

If you want to change the format template dynamically, `String.Format` will work better, as you can specify the format and the value as separate arguments.

*(Example assumes an enum `FormatKind` and C# >= 8.0)*

```cs
int value = 1;
string format = formatKind switch {
    FormatKind.CstSmall => "CST-{0:d3}",
    FormatKind.CstLarge => "CST-{0:d6}",
    FormatKind.Hello => "HELLO{0:d3}",
    FormatEnum.Customer => "CUSTOMER{0:d4}"
};
string result = String.Format(format, value);
```

Also note that the value to be formatted must be of a numeric type. Strings cannot be formatted.

See also: [Composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

It seems `.toString("CST-000")`, `.toString("HELLO000")` and so on, does the trick.

Comment: Might be in that special case. But be aware, that certain characters have certain meanings in a format string, which might lead to unwanted results

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with a format string of e.g. `WEE0000`

Answer (score 0):

ToString and String.Format can do much more than use predefined formats.

For example :

```
string result = string.Format("CST-{0:000000}", 1);

string result = 1.ToString("CST-000000");
```

Should both do what you want.

(Of course you could replace "1" by any variable, even a decimal one).

Comment: Note that your last example doesn't work with a format string of e.g. `WEE0000`

Comment: @canton7 you're right. I don't know all kind of syntax for ToString but maybe it's nonetheless possible to write a working formatter for this one. Including what may be required to escape some characters that are "reserved"

Comment: [They're listed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings). The problem is that pesky `E0` format